# Where to find a Seq2SeqTrainer to import into project?

Tags: python, nlp, seq2seq

Like the title says, I require a Seq2SeqTrainer for my project, but the file/s on Github are not available and return a 404. I use this code to try and import it:

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/transformers/master/examples/seq2seq/seq2seq_trainer.py
```

If it's no longer available anywhere, what would be a good alternative as I want to use ROUGE as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found a solution. The file can be found at:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/seq2seq/seq2seq_trainer.py

For some reason when importing the file Python picks up a commented link and throws an error. To get around this simply make a copy of the file without the comments at the top. That worked for me.

EDIT: I found a neater solution:

```
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer
```